# Images not showing after changing Web API url with https

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httpclient

When the web API's url is with http, images are loading very smoothly and app is working great. (http://projectName.lk/sites/default/files/mini.jpg). But after I changed API's url to https, (https://projectName.lk/sites/default/files/mini.jpg) any service didn't work.

Then I did this and app worked. (Droid settings -> Androis Options -> Advanced -> changed **HttpClient implementation** to Android. But images didn't load. Any image didn't load.

[image]
Service view in browser.

[image]

ImageUrl[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbFmK.jpg) -  https://projectName.lk/sites/default/files/mini-9788131533564.jpg

FullBookImageURL - https://projectName.lk/sites/default/files/mini-9788131533564.jpg

[image]

Xaml file

But any image not loading. When open the url in browser, image is showing.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use a simple `<Image>` control and test if you can see the image using it.

Comment: @GeralexGR [s]he used `FFImageLoading` library which doesn't support standard `Image` widget.

Comment: Did you try in real mobile device?

Comment: @GeralexGR Yes. That worked for me. For some reason, that FFImageLoading is not working with that iimage url.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani yes of course.

Comment: That happens in specific android version or all versions? please be more specific about this kind of info

Comment: In all android versions. But this happens, only when I'm getting images from our site. FFImageLoading finely working in images from other sources..